# Sarxos Webcam-Capture error - "We shouldn't be here..."

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, webcam-capture, boofcv

Currently, I'm working towards running [WebcamScanQR.java](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/ExampleWebcamRPI/blob/master/src/main/java/WebcamScanQR.java) from BoofCV on my Raspberry Pi. As I'm having problems with that I thought it'd be best to start with trying to get [DetectWebcamExample.java](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture/src/example/java/DetectWebcamExample.java) working.

However, I get a long list of errors found [here](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/issues/854). I couldn't fit all of the error code into this question unfortunately. This is also the link to my original GitHub issue I raised.

It then goes on to loop "we shouldn't be here..." for infinity. I'm new to working with Raspberry Pis' and camera drivers. I was just wondering if someone could provide some insight to this problem? As far as I'm aware, I have all imports and dependencies sorted but then again I may be wrong. Here is the link to my [pom.xml](https://github.com/johnl5124/ACORobotics/blob/main/pom.xml) file.

Comment: Please don't link to other sources, include all relevant information in the question here. Links can break or change (especially github links), making the question unusable for others with similar problems.

Comment: https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Raspberry_PI#How_do_I_get_webcams_to_work.3F Does that help?